# How do I expose a component via block params in Ember 1.10 + HTMLBars

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

With block params, I thought the following would work to expose a component to a nested control without need of the `_yield` hack.

```
{{#my-component as |myparam|}}
    {{log myparam}}
{{/my-component}}
```

This does not appear to work, as this log returns undefined.

I'm using `ember-cli 0.1.15` `ember 1.10.0` and `ember-cli-htmlbars 0.7.4`.  Is there something I need to do to enable block params, or is this not the correct notation?

**UPDATE**

For an example usage, consider a flexible carousel with slides and control buttons.

```
{{#carousel-component as |carousel|}}
    {{#slide-component}}
      <button {{action "nextSlide" target=carousel}}>Next</button>
    {{/slide}}
{{/carousel-component}}
```

And to be specific, this is an attempt at solving this use case strictly using the new `block params` syntax available in Ember 1.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html, it looks like the new syntax needs block params passed via the component's `yield` helper.  I've made a JSBin to illustrate:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jacosewefu/4/edit

Comment: @runspired Updated my answer, looks like `{{yield}}` needs to become `{{yield controller}}` :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Passing the entire component as a block-param goes the principle of isolation, so unless there is an exceptional reason, pass specific arguments instead.**

Use this as template for your component:

```
{{yield context}}
```

Then, as you write:

```
{{#carousel-component as |carousel|}}
    {{#slide-component}}
      <button {{action "nextSlide" target=carousel}}>Next</button>
    {{/slide}}
{{/carousel-component}}
```

*More on block params:*
http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html#toc_block-params